# add and remove class on the base of selected value

Tags: jquery, html

```html
<div class="availability-form">
  <select class="awe-select" id="dayss">
    <option value="one">For 1 Day</option>
    <option value="more">For More Days</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="book_date" id="arrival" class="awe-calendar" placeholder="Booking Date">
  <input type="text" name="book_dep_date" id="departure" class="awe-calendar" placeholder="Booking Departure Date">
  <div class="vailability-submit">
    <button class="awe-btn awe-btn-13" type="submit" name="chk" style="margin-top: -9px;margin-left: 20px;">FIND Availability</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dayss').on('change', function() {
    var a = $('#dayss').val();
    if (a == 'one') {
      $('#departure').removeClass('awe-calendar'),
        $('#departure').addClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $('#departure').removeClass('hidden'),
        $('#departure').addClass('awe-calendar');
    }
  });
});
```

when if condition have true , there only 'addClass('hidden')' worked not work 'removeClass(awe-calendar)'. Please help.

Comment: remove comma (,) after `$('#departure').removeClass('awe-calendar')`.

Comment: what sort of control is #dayss? is it an input / textbox or something else? select, etc.

Comment: #dayss is an select tag.

Comment: I think the issue was only because of the comma, which will throw an exception...

Comment: There are like 10 duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dayss').on('change', function(){
        var a  = $('#dayss').val();
        if(a == 'one') {
            $('#departure').removeClass('awe-calendar').addClass('hidden');
        }
        else{
            $('#departure').removeClass('hidden').addClass('awe-calendar');
        }
    });
});
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dayss').on('change', function(){
        var a  = $('#dayss').val();
        if(a == 'one') {
            $('#departure').removeClass('awe-calendar').addClass('hidden');
        }
        else{
            $('#departure').removeClass('hidden').addClass('awe-calendar');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
.awe-calendar{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="availability-form">
  <select class="awe-select" id="dayss">
    <option value="one">For 1 Day</option>
    <option value="more">For More Days</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="book_date" id="arrival" class="awe-calendar" placeholder="Booking Date">
  <input type="text" name="book_dep_date" id="departure" class="hidden" placeholder="Booking Departure Date">
  <div class="vailability-submit">
    <button class="awe-btn awe-btn-13" type="submit" name="chk" style="margin-top: -9px;margin-left: 20px;">FIND Availability</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i try this one but face same problem.only 'hidden' class added not removed 'awe-calendar'.

Comment: @ManishSuthar Can you add the `html` also?

Comment: @ManishSuthar I have updated my answer as well. Check my demo